# facebook social plug-in not showing up when added dynamically

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am adding facebook social plug in to a webpage

when I manually add :

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://website.com/z" data-width="700" data-numposts="7" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

it works , however , when javascript code add it , it doesn't

any ideas ?

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow it, so it generally doesn't work unless the script is present on pageload. There's probably workarounds ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The JS SDK goes through your document once when it is initialized, to look for such elements to parse into social plugins. If you want it to also parse content that you add to the document later, you need to call `FB.XFBML.parse()`.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Comment: Thanks Cbro, this helped me a lot! :)

Comment: This fixed a two day problem for me! Thank you so much, @CBroe!

Comment: I wish I could give you 100+, weirdly I was looking for this in the docs and never found it :')

Comment: You Are Wonderful !

Answer (score 0):

That was great @CBroe!

Thank you! It worked in a Nextjs/React project.

As a reference, please, see a custom hook implementing it:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
let FB;

const useFacebook = ({ addTrack }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
 
    const facebookScript = document.createElement("script");

    facebookScript.id = 'fb-sdk';
    facebookScript.async = true;
    facebookScript.defer = true;
    facebookScript.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    facebookScript.nonce = "5JOEwLPT";
    const track = addTrack ? `&appId=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FACEBOOK_ID}&autoLogAppEvents=1` : '';
    facebookScript.src = `https://connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v10.0${track}`;

    document.body.appendChild(facebookScript);

    const startScript = document.createElement('script');
    const code = `window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId            : '${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FACEBOOK_ID}',
        autoLogAppEvents : ${addTrack},
        xfbml            : true,
        version          : 'v10.0'
      });
    };`;
    startScript.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
    document.body.appendChild(startScript);
    if(window.FB) {
      window.fbAsyncInit();
    }
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(facebookScript);
      document.body.removeChild(startScript);
    }
  }, [addTrack]);
};

export default useFacebook;
```

Full code Nextjs Facebook SDK comments sample:
https://github.com/cmdaniel/nextjs-facebook-sdk