# How to display Facebook like button using React.js

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like, reactjs

I wrote a like button class in react to display facebook like button in my blog posts

```
var LikeButton = React.createClass(
{
    render : function ()
    {
        var url = "http://yahya.skaprer.com/p/" + this.props.obd;
        return (
            <div className="fb-like" data-href={url} data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>
        );
    }
});
```

The button doesn't show up no matter what I do. I checked running FB in console to check whether the SDK is installed properly and yes it has. Is there any bug in my code or is this the wrong way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29133563/facebook-social-plug-in-not-showing-up-when-added-dynamically/29134477#29134477