# Not able to display facebook share button in bootstrap accordion function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, facebook

Hi i am using bootstrap accordion to display data and i am using facebook share button to share my post in social media but not able to show the share button.Here is my code.

```
<?php if(isset($records2) && is_array($records2)):?>
                <?php foreach ($records2 as $r):?>

                <div class="digitalmarketingassociate">
                  <span class="digit"><?php echo $r->job_name ;?></span>
                  <div class="applynow">Apply Now</div>
                  <div class="moreinfo accordion" >More Info</div>
                    <div class="panel">         

                            <h3 class="job">Job Description</h3>
                            <p class="jobdes"><?php echo $r->job_description ;?></p>

                            <h3 class="job">Desired Skills & Experience</h3>
                            <p class=""desiredskills"><?php echo $r->skills_experience ;?></p>

                            <h3 class="job">Educational Qualification</h3>
                            <p class="educationalqua"><?php echo $r->qualification ;?></p>

                            <h3 class="job">Roles and Responsibilities</h3>
                            <ul class="rolesand">
                                <li class="rolesandres"><?php echo $r->roles_responsibilities;?></li>
                            </ul>

                            <h3 class="job">What we offer</h3>
                            <p class="whatweoffer"><?php echo $r->what_we_offer ;?></p>                                

                            <h3 class="job">How to apply</h3>
                            <p class="howtoapp">Email us your resume along with your Linkedin profile on <a href="mailto:hrmanager@xxxxx.com" class="hrmanager">hrmanager@xxxxxx.com</a> Alternatively, you can also apply via <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>theme/images/testimonial/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin" /></p>

                            <h3  class="job">Share this job</h3>                                
   <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php echo base_url()?>career/careers/<?php echo $r ->jobs_id ;?>"data-layout="button_count"></div>
                            <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a><script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
                            <span class="linkedincount"><script type="IN/Share" data-url="<?php echo base_url()?>career/careers/<?php echo $r ->jobs_id ;?>" data-counter="right"></script></span>
                            <div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-height="24" data-href="<?php echo base_url()?>career/careers/<?php echo $r ->jobs_id ;?>"></div>

                    </div>

                </div> 
                <?php endforeach ;endif;?>
```

Here i have used  so it is not able to show the facebook share button in accordion function.

Clicking on More Info button it will show more information regarding the post which we have posted.But here it is not displaying the facebook share button or linkedin share button etcc.. 
If i remove the  then it will display the social media share buttons.It will display total information of the post if we are not using  then but it should not show in that format.It should show only job name once we click on more info then only it should display the information of the post including sharing options.

Comment: Does it show if you put it outside?

Comment: If i remove <div class="panel"> then it is working fine else it is not showing that share option.

Comment: It is because the panel body is not visible in the DOM. Is it display:none initially?

Comment: No it is not display:none

Comment: What type of accordion is it then?

Comment: @hunzaboy sorry at the beginning it will display only job name and the panel body will be display:none once i click on more info button it will show the information in the panel body except scoial sharing buttons.

Comment: The SDK ignores elements that are not visible at the time of its initialization. If you want to get such elements parsed as well, you need to call FB.XFBML.parse when they become visible for the first time.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/29134477/1427878

Comment: @Ashalatha, Tha's the issue. Refer to the link shared above.

Comment: Another approach is to use opacity and visibility instead of display property.

Comment: @hunzaboy actually i am using codeigniter php i need to call FB.XFBML in the html file itself.It is not only for facebook twitter,linkedin,google plus it is not displaying any one.

Comment: @hunzaboy i am not getting to which class property i need to use opacity or else visibility properties.

Comment: @hunzaboy can you edit in my question it will be helpful for me

Comment: Anyone who can sort out my problem it will be really helpful thank you in advance