# facebook SDK embedded post only showing when doing hard reload

Tags: typescript, user-interface, next.js, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to share facebook posts on my clients website. I did as mentioned [facebook embedded post documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts).

I'm here using React NEXT.js framework.

Added the SDK right after opening body tag in my _document.tsx.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v11.0"
```

nonce="Z4T7Zvkv">

Then I added the code in required page.

```
<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/20531316728/posts/10154009990506729/" data-width="500" data-show-text="true"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/20531316728/posts/10154009990506729/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Posted by <a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebookapp/">Facebook App</a> on&nbsp;<a href="https://www.facebook.com/20531316728/posts/10154009990506729/">Thursday, 27 August 2015</a></blockquote></div>
```

I want to show the post as mention in the documentation.
[Image - Post shown in the documention](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtU81.png)

But I'm getting the post as below image.
[Image - Post showing in my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWTm4.png)

In chrome if I did Normal Reload the post not showing but only the blockqoute text.
But when I'm doiing the Hard Reload then it's showing but right after a Normal Reload then the blockqoute text is showing.

Please help to me fix this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [facebook social plug-in not showing up when added dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29133563/facebook-social-plug-in-not-showing-up-when-added-dynamically)

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue. `FB.XFBML.parse()` in my useEffect it worked.

```
useEffect(() => {
  FB.XFBML.parse();
}, []);
```

[Read more about it here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/)